# TinyMCE Angular 5 cannot find themes/modern/theme.js

Tags: angular, tinymce

So I am trying to use TinyMCE for an editor within an application. and I have correctly installed the npm module, copied the skin into my assets folder and correctly added the scripts to my angular-cli.json. Here is what I have done with my `EditorComponent`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

import 'tinymce';

declare var tinymce: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.component.scss']
})
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @Input() elementId: string;
  @Output() onEditorKeyup = new EventEmitter<any>();

  editor: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#' + this.elementId,
      plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table'],
      skin_url: 'assets/skins/lightgray',
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
        });
      } 
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }

}
```

and here is the markup for the `EditorComponent`:

```
<textarea id="{{elementId}}"></textarea>
```

and now being used in a parent component:

```
<app-editor [elementId]="'editor'" (onEditorKeyup)="keyupHandlerFunction($event)"></app-editor>
```

I have followed this link from their website: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/

in addition to a few other posts showing how to declare `tinymce` in the component.

Here is the angular-cli.json app[0].scripts as well:

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.js",
        "../node_modules/tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.js"
      ]
```

I seem to be getting this error in my console which is thrown by tinymce.js:

[image]

But I cannot find a replicated issue anywhere out there, and the console log gives no clue to where in my code this issue is arising. My editor component also just shows up completely blank in the parent component. I appreciate any and all help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

I had a very similar issue, and I discovered that somehow TinyMCE changed the location of where it was seeking the asset archives from

```
"/tinymce/skins/",
"/tinymce/themes/",
"/tinymce/plugins/",
```

to

```
"/skins/",
"/themes/",
"/plugins/",
```

Because of this the output in the assets config in the Angular.json file was wrong and I had to fix it from:

```
{ "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/skins", "output": "/tinymce/skins/" },
{ "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/themes", "output": "/tinymce/themes/" },
{ "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/plugins", "output": "/tinymce/plugins/" }
```

To:

```
{ "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/skins", "output": "/skins/" },
{ "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/themes", "output": "/themes/" },
{ "glob": "**/*", "input": "node_modules/tinymce/plugins", "output": "/plugins/" }
```

Unfortunately, I have not found out what caused the change in behaviour but I do believe this is a better answer than manually importing the scripts or copying them inside your application folder.

Comment: By far and away the best solution to this issue, simple and easy to replicate. Thanks, Rafael Bronzatti.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error and got it working in Angular 5:

Copy the 3 Folders "plugins", "skins", "themes" from the "node_modules/tinymce" folder into your apps "assets" folder.

Also set the baseURL for tinymce to your assets folder afterwards

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.baseURL = 'assets';
    tinymce.init({
      selector: '#' + this.elementId,
      plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table'],
      skin_url: 'assets/skins/lightgray',
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
        });
      },
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, going to try this tonight when I can get on that project and will let you know how it goes

Comment: Hey I am sorry for getting back to this so late. I have tried the edits above and now I just get a basic textarea element in my editor component, but no errors in my console now so I am at a loss of where to move forward. I always appreciate the advice though!

Answer (score 2):

Well actually I had the same problem but in my Syfomny 4 project with webpack. I've searched in many places and ended up with my own idea which works - at least at this moment.

First of all in **js file** that's gonna have tinymce logic add:

```
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce';
import 'tinymce/themes/silver';
```

Now this article: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-setup-tinymce-in-your-rails-app-using-webpack-edf030915332 says that You can use this:

```
import ‘tinymce/skins/lightgray/skin.min.css’;
```

but it will not work, since there is no such file as **skin.min.css**.

The solution is to import every single file like:

```
import 'tinymce/skins/content/default/content.css';
import 'tinymce/skins/content/document/content.css';
import 'tinymce/skins/content/writer/content.css';
import 'tinymce/skins/ui/oxide-dark/content.css';
```

but then this destroys the page theme...

So the final solution is adding wrapper for form which will have the tiny-mce:

```
<section id="tiny-mce-wrapper">
    <form>
        <textarea class="tiny-mce"></textarea>
    </form>
</section>
```

then:

- **move all csses from node/modules/tinymce/skin** into place where You store Your css.
- change extension of all files from css to scss
- in each file add changes so that the styles will apply **only** for Your tinmce  textarea when it's inside **#tiny-mce**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late. Here I found the issue on GitHub:

> https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/4164

The temporary solution is to import your scripts like this:

```
    "../node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js",
    "../node_modules/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.js"
```

Or wait to the next version.

Sorry for my bad english, have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You might lost the theme folder bundled with the `tinymce` directory. Now look into the `theme` folder if there is no `modern` folder then got to: https://www.tiny.cloud/get-tiny/self-hosted/, download the version you prefer and configure to your project manually.

Hope this will help! :)